# Is the Fourier-Stieltjes algebra of a locally compact group semi-simple?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, harmonic-analysis, banach-algebras

Let $G$ be a locally compact group. Is the Fourier-Stieltjes  algebra $B(G)$ semi-simple?

Comment: Yes. Surely this should be explained in Eymard's 1964 article? Also, the tag you have chosen for this question is not really relevant, I have re-tagged

Comment: When you say semisimple do you mean semiprimitive (trivial Jacobson radical)?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I am certain, given the context, that the answer to your question is yes -- this is the standard terminology among those reading about or working on Banach algebras

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(The following was originally a comment, but I've moved it to an answer. Please don't TeXify this.)

---

Recall that for commutative unital algebras, the Jacobson radical is exactly the set of quasi-nilpotent elements. By definition (see e.g. [Eymard's original 1964 article](http://www.numdam.org/item?id=BSMF_1964__92__181_0)), B(G) is an algebra of functions – you do not need to define it as a completion – and for each x in G, "evaluation at x" is a character on the unital, commutative Banach algebra B(G). So if f is a quasi-nilpotent element of B(G) then it lies in the kernel of every character, hence f(x)=0 for all x in G, hence f = 0.

Comment: Could you put an easy link to Eymard's original paper ? thanks.